# Сетка на экране эмулятора Android

Tags: android

На экране эмулятора всегда рисуется сетка, заметная на светлом фоне. Как её убрать?

Comment: если окно эмулятора подвигать вправо-влево, сетка передвигается вместе с окном или остается на месте (относительно монитора).

Comment: передвигается с окном

Comment: попытался воспроизвести - пока никак.

Эмулятор какой именно версии?

Comment: Android emulator version 20.0 (build_id OPENMASTER-391819)
под ubuntu 12.4
сетка светло-серая слабозаметная 8х8 пикселей, экранная лупа её увеличивает, так что это не глюк монитора.

Comment: 8х8 - очень похоже на артефакты от jpeg.

Comment: Возможно, тем более что при более пристальном разглядывании заметны другие ещё более слабые артефакты

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поставьте [другой скин](https://www.google.com/#hl=en&q=android+emulator+skins) эмулятора. В сети полно скинов, в т.ч. на популярные модели реальных телефонов

Comment: изменился размер сетки

Comment: В общем похоже это проявляется когда экран эмулятора больше экрана компьютера.
Сделал размер чуть поменьше - сетка пропала

Answer (score 0):

Не задавался такой целью, но когда создавал проект специально для больших экранов с использованием фрагментов сетка не появлялась, да и на маленьких экранах никогда ее не видел